# Finding constants for second order diff. equation with repeated real root

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

http://personal.psu.edu/sxt104/class/Math251/Notes-2nd%20order%20ODE%20pt1.pdf

On Page 28 of the above link it shows example of how to find general form of second order diff. equation with repeated root.

The equation is $y″ − 4y′ + 4y = 0$ with condition $y(0) = 4$, $y′(0) = 5$.

But how they find the constants using initial conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have
$$
y(t)=C_1e^{2t}+C_2te^{2t}
$$
you can differentiate and
$$
y'(t)=2C_1e^{2t}+C_2(2te^{2t}+e^{2t}).
$$
Now, let's plug in the conditions $y(0)=4, y'(0)=5$.
$$
\begin{cases}
4=y(0)=C_1e^0+C_2e^0 \cdot 0=C_1\\
5=y'(0)=2C_1e^0+C_2(2e^0 \cdot 0+e^0)=2C_1+C_2.
\end{cases}
$$
From the first equation $C_1=4$ and from the second equation $C_2=5-2C_1=5-8=-3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'' − 4y′ + 4y = 0$$
Is equivalent to:
$$(ye^{-2x})''=0$$
Integrate twice.
$$y=e^{2x}(c_1x+c_2)$$
$$y'=e^{2x}(2c_1x+c_1+2c_2)$$
Apply intial condtions:
$$y(0)=4 \implies 4=c_2$$
$$y'(0)=5 \implies 5=c_1+2c_2 \implies c_1=-3$$